# Issue with bottom margin of image elements

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

[image]

The image is from [Explanation about viable prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202181/explanation-about-viable-prefix/27651270#27651270).

I'm not sure it's a bug, but it will look better without the bottom margin.